# Show hidden divs in the new clone () div

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

Any suggestions on how to keep the hidden (display:none) div hidden but make it show up in the new clone div?.

The clone works When I take away the display style but i need it to be hidden. I have extensively tried to research and fix the issue with no luck. (maybe because i am a beginner coder)

Here is my code:

(div for new clones)

```
<div class="showcontent" class="toggle"></div>
```

(.poster div containing elements to be cloned)

```
<div class=poster><img width='<?php 67*2.3 ?>' height='<?= 98*2.3 ?>' src='<?= $movie['image_url'] ?>'> <br>
<div class=title><h1text><?= $movie['title'] ?></h1text>  </div>  <br>
<span class=year>(<?= $movie['year'] ?>)</span> 
<div class=title style="display:none"><h1text><?= $movie['title'] ?></h1text>  </div>  <br> </div>
```

(script)

```
$(".poster").click(function(){
img = $(this).clone();
$(".showcontent").show().html(img.removeAttr(''));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".poster").click(function(){
  var divNewPoster = $(this).clone();

  divNewPoster.find("div").show();
  // or if you want to be more selective:
  divNewPoster.find(".title").show();

  $(".showcontent").empty().show().append(divNewPoster);
});
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do you `empty()`>`show()`>`append()` rather than `html()`>`show()`?

Comment: @DBS I don't recall `$().html()` function with jQuery wrapper object as parameter.

Comment: I was just trying things I was learning and that happened to work until I needed to show a hidden div